# Is there a way to change the location of pytest's .cache directory?

Tags: python, caching, directory, pytest

I need to be able to change the location of pytest's .cache directory to the env variable, WORKSPACE. Due to server permissions out of my control, I am running into this error because my user does not have permission to write in the directory where the tests are being run from:

```
py.error.EACCES: [Permission denied]: open('/path/to/restricted/directory/tests/.cache/v/cache/lastfailed', 'w')
```

Is there a way to set the path of the .cache directory to the environment variable WORKSPACE?

Answer (score 31):

You can prevent the creation of `.cache/` by disabling the "cacheprovider" plugin:

```
py.test -p no:cacheprovider ...
```

Answer (score 26):

See built-in help available per [`pytest -h` or `pytest --help`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#command-line-flags):

If you prefer to use a command line argument, you can use a `-o` or `--override-ini=...` switch:

```
pytest tests -o cache_dir=.my_cache_dir
```

Alternatively, starting from pytest 3.2, you can specify the [`cache_dir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#confval-cache_dir) option in the [`pytest` configuration file](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#configuration-file-formats) (called [`pytest.ini`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) by default):

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
cache_dir = .my_cache_dir
```

If you prefer a custom configuration file name, you may use e.g.

```
pytest tests -c .my_pytest.ini
```

Comment: Do not forget to mention `[pytest]` section in the .ini file

Comment: starting from pytest 6.0 it has been also possible to place the `cache_dir` option to `[tool.pytest.ini_options]` in pyproject.toml.

Answer (score 8):

You can create an empty file called `pytest.ini` in one of the parent directories of your test, are that will become the `rootdir` in which the `.cache` will be created.

See https://pytest.org/latest/customize.html

It's not ideal but it allows some form of customization.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit option to change the cache directory on the command line, but it is possible to override the options in pytest.ini with the `-o` option instead:

`pytest -o cache_dir=$WORKSPACE ...`

See the output of `pytest --help` for more info about the `-o` option.

Also, for reference I'm using pytest 3.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:cacheprovider
```